# No route matches [PATCH] "/jobs/2/tasks"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I'm newbie to Rails. I'm trying to do nested. I have jobs, and each of them is assigned task, but when I try update task I get an error `No route matches [PATCH] "/ jobs / 2 / tasks"`

Should I make changes in route?

Thanks in advance

My route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'jobs#index'
  resources :sessions
  resources :users


  resources :jobs do
    resources :tasks
    end

   match 'jobs/:job_id/tasks', to: "jobs/tasks#index", via: :get

 get 'admin' => 'jobs#index'
end
```

Tasks/form

```
<%= form_for @task, url: job_tasks_path do |f| %>
    <% if @task.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :text %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :text %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Tasks controller

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to job_tasks_url, notice: 'Zadanie zostało pomyslnie zmienione.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand how to debug this error, you can start by running rake routes in the terminal. The output will look something like

```
            Prefix    Verb    URI Pattern                                   Controller#Action
            job_tasks GET    /jobs/:job_id/tasks(.:format)                 tasks#index
                      POST   /jobs/:job_id/tasks(.:format)                 tasks#create
         new_job_task GET    /jobs/:job_id/tasks/new(.:format)             tasks#new
        edit_job_task GET    /jobs/:job_id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format)        tasks#edit
             job_task GET    /jobs/:job_id/tasks/:id(.:format)             tasks#show
                      PATCH  /jobs/:job_id/tasks/:id(.:format)             tasks#update
                      PUT    /jobs/:job_id/tasks/:id(.:format)             tasks#update
                      DELETE /jobs/:job_id/tasks/:id(.:format)             tasks#destroy
                 jobs GET    /jobs(.:format)                               jobs#index
                      POST   /jobs(.:format)                               jobs#create
              new_job GET    /jobs/new(.:format)                           jobs#new
             edit_job GET    /jobs/:id/edit(.:format)                      jobs#edit
                  job GET    /jobs/:id(.:format)                           jobs#show
                      PATCH  /jobs/:id(.:format)                           jobs#update
                      PUT    /jobs/:id(.:format)                           jobs#update
                      DELETE /jobs/:id(.:format)                           jobs#destroy
```

The left hand column gives you the name of the route. You can refer to it in your views and controllers as job_tasks_path or job_tasks_url, basically appending _path or _url to the named route. The next column gives you the HTTP verb. Notice that for update and destroy you need to specify the verb PATCH or PUT, and DELETE respectively. This is how rails matches its requests with HTTP requests. The next column shows you the format the uri takes and the far right column shows how the route is matched to a controller and an action. A colon indicates that a parameter needs to be provided.

job_tasks will send the request to the index action in the tasks controller and expect a job_id parameter to be provided, which you can access via params[:job_id].

The error you're getting says that your form is trying to post to a uri that doesn't exist. [PATCH] / jobs / 2 / tasks doesn't exist but [PATCH] "/ jobs / job_id / tasks / :id does. Change your form_tag to

```
<%= form_for @task, url: job_tasks_path(@job) do |f| %>
```

or

```
<%= form_for([@job, @task]) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this route is not required as the `resources :tasks` about is already creating it for you

```
match 'jobs/:job_id/tasks', to: "jobs/tasks#index", via: :get
```

Secondly, in the form you are missig the job: `job_tasks_path` should be something like `job_tasks_path(@job)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn more about nested resources, the link below is a good example that I followed when I first tried nested resources too:
(it is a bit old so you may have to update some code yourself)

> Creating nested resources in ruby on rails 3 and updating scaffolding links and redirection:
>   https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/3074080